# Dynamic images from array

Tags: gatsby

In Gatsby, how do I display images if the path is dynamic?

I have an array like this:

```js
const pics = [
    {
        title: "doggo",
        src: "../images/dog.png",
    },
    {
        title: "kitty",
        src: "../images/cat.png",
    },
];
```

I understand that I can't use the StaticImage component, so I take it I need to use the GastbyImage component instead, getting my images via a GraphQL query. But how?

PS: I use "gatsby-plugin-image" that comes with the default installer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to allow Gatsby to create queryable nodes from those images by setting the filesystem like:

```
const path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src`, `images`),
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

In the build time, Gatsby will identify the `/src/images` folder and will create  GraphQL nodes after treating your images with their transformers and sharps.

You'll have exposed some useful filters and nodes regarding the filesystem configuration, test it in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` but they should look like:

```
{
  allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" } }) {
    edges {
      node {
       childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData(
            width: 200
            placeholder: BLURRED
            formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `sourceInstanceName` `images` stands for the `name` property in the `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

Your images data is held by `props.data.allFile.node` so in any page you just can:

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

function YourPage({ data }) {

 return (
   <section>
   {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node }) => <GatsbyImage image={node.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData})} alt={node.title} key={node.title}/>
   </section>
 )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
 query {
   allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" } }) {
     edges {
       node {
        title
        childImageSharp {
           gatsbyImageData(
             width: 200
             placeholder: BLURRED
             formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
           )
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
`
```

Tweak it to refine it to your requirements or specifications.